# No carga la informacion en un arrary json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Buenas a todos tengo un problemas, estoy realizando un consulta a mi base de datos y la estoy guardando en mi array json pero al momento de cargarlo no me muestra nada, alguien me podria decir que puede ser  y como lo puedo solucionar . muchas gracias

La tabla de mi base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has un `var_dump` de `$json2` y dinos que salida obtienes

Comment: lo hice y si me muestra la información

Comment: como puedo hacer para que me muestra la información con echo json_encode. lo curioso es que tengo otro archivo y si me funciona

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código **como texto**. [Aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/19610) tienes una guía de que hacer y que no al formular preguntas. Un saludo.